# How can a PHP application in Bluemix use the SQL Database service?

Tags: php, sql, db2, ibm-cloud

I am deploying a web app using Bluemix. I am using PHP and the SQL Database service. But I have a question: How can I link my PHP code to make a query to an SQL Database in Bluemix?

Comment: This question also addresses using the SQL DB service from PHP: [How can I convert a project to use the Bluemix SQL Database instead of the Bluemix mySQL Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117789/how-can-i-convert-a-project-to-use-the-bluemix-sql-database-instead-of-the-bluem)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [sample project](https://hub.jazz.net/project/communitysample/php-mysql/overview) that uses php to connect to the MySQL service in Bluemix. The docs ([SQL](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html) and [MySQL](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MySQL/index.html)) also discuss the topic in depth.

If you have a specific issue, comment below. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An additional article you might find helpful: "[Build and deploy a REST API on IBM Bluemix with PHP and MySQL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-deployrest-app/index.html)."